# Using Hold correctly with Simplify and ComplexityFunction

Tags: simplifying-expressions

It seems like Mathematica immediately evaluates the expression `Sqrt@I` to `(-1)^(1/4)`. I'm trying to use `Simplify` with my own `ComplexityFunction f` in such a way, that `Simplify[Sqrt@I]` returns `Sqrt@I`, which (in my opinion) is the simpler expression. Hence, I've defined the following `f`:

```
Attributes[f]=HoldAll;
f[expr_]:=StringLength@ToString@HoldForm@expr
```

Testing it yields the expected results:

```
f[Sqrt@I]
f[(-1)^(1/4)]
```

> 7
>
> 12

Now, when I call `Simplify[Sqrt@I, ComplexityFunction->f]` it still returns `(-1)^(1/4)`. I believe this is due to the fact that after the simplification (which should return `Sqrt@I`), the expression is in turn evaluated to `(-1)^(1/4)`. Can I define `f` in such a way that this last evaluation is not performed? Can I use `HoldForm` to achieve this?

Comment: A side note: `(f@#&)` is redundant; you can use simply `f`.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I wasn't sure if the head of the right side of `ComplexityFunction` needed to be `Function`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe your function works correctly but the automatic transformation functions used by `Simplify` lack a rule that converts `(-1)^(1/4)` into `Sqrt[I]`.  Also, your observation that the reverse transformation happens automatically is correct, therefore even with the right transformation function you do not get the result you want.  However, you can `Hold` the expression to prevent this.

```
Attributes[f] = HoldAll;
f[expr_] := StringLength @ ToString @ HoldForm @ expr

tf = # /. HoldPattern[(-1)^(1/4)] :> Sqrt @ I &;

Simplify[Hold[(-1)^(1/4)], ComplexityFunction -> f, TransformationFunctions -> tf]
```

> ```
> Hold[Sqrt[I]]
> ```

I used a transformation rule that explicitly performs the replacement you desire.  It also operates inside of `Hold` which the default transformations do not.  This isn't particuarly helpful I fear but it does illustrate that with the right `ComplexityFunction` and `TransformationFunctions` settings `Simplify` can perform the operation you want.  Crafting those functions may be difficult however.

---

I took another look at this, and it seems that the custom `ComplexityFunction` is not needed here.  I also found that `(-1)^(1/4)` may be represented in at least two different internal forms which illustrates the complexity of crafting your own rules.  (In practice if any transformations can be done with built-in functions rather than manual pattern matching they should be done that way.)

```
auto = Replace[#, x_ :> With[{eval = FullSimplify[x]}, eval /; True], -1] &;
tf = # /. HoldPattern[(-1)^(1/4) | (-1)^Rational[1, 4]] :> Sqrt[I] &;

expr = Hold[1/(3 (1 + x)) - (-1 + 2 x)/(6 (1 - x + x^2)) +
            2/(3 (1 + 1/3 (-1 + 2 x)^2)) + (-1)^(1/4)];

Simplify[expr, TransformationFunctions -> {auto, tf}]
```

> ```
> Hold[Sqrt[I] + 1/(1 + x^3)]
> ```

Notice that in the rule `auto` I am calling `FullSimplify` to access the default rules, and I am using the [Trott-Strzebonski method for In-Place Evaluation](http://library.wolfram.com/conferences/devconf99/villegas/UnevaluatedExpressions/Links/index_lnk_30.html) to make these apply inside `Hold`.

Comment: Thank You! That's pretty much what I wanted to hear. I didn't know how to use `TransformationFunctions` correctly.

Comment: @einbandi I updated my answer with an example that I hope you will find more practical.