# How to make rational expressions formatted using FractionBox

Tags: output-formatting

This is what I get using Mathematica 9.0.1.

[image]

[image]

Instead I want this:

[image]

I know how to use MakeBoxes, Format and I thought this code would work:

```
MakeBoxes[(1/2)(expr_), StandardForm]:=
FractionBox[ MakeBoxes[expr, StandardForm], MakeBoxes[2, StandardForm]]
```

But the code above and all variations that I tried have no effect. This has to be automated to get the look I want. My actual application is much more complicated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple internal forms of `x / 2`.  I ran into the same problem here (with `1/4`):
[Using Hold correctly with Simplify and ComplexityFunction](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18149/121)

This appears to work in all cases:

```
MakeBoxes[expr_ / 2 | Rational[1, 2] expr_, fmt_] := 
  FractionBox[MakeBoxes[expr, fmt], "2"]

(3 + Sin[t])/2
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can better see what is going on with `FullForm`:

```
HoldForm @ FullForm[expr_/2]
HoldForm @ FullForm[Rational[1, 2]*expr_]
```

> ```
> Times[Pattern[expr,Blank[]],Power[2,-1]]
>
> Times[Rational[1,2],Pattern[expr,Blank[]]]
> ```

You need to cover both the `Power[2,-1]` and `Rational[1, 2]` cases with your pattern.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd accept a replacement rule, this could be done as follows:

```
oneHalf /: MakeBoxes[oneHalf[expr_], StandardForm] := 
 FractionBox[MakeBoxes[expr, StandardForm], MakeBoxes[2, StandardForm]]

(3 + Sin[x])/2 /. (expr_)/2 :> oneHalf[expr]
```

> $$\frac{3+\text{Sin}[x]}{2}$$

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, something like:

```
 frctnBx /: MakeBoxes[frctnBx[expr_], StandardForm] :=
 With[{num = Numerator[expr], denom = Denominator[expr]},
  Switch[denom, 1, MakeBoxes[num, StandardForm],
  _, FractionBox[MakeBoxes[num, StandardForm], 
  MakeBoxes[denom, StandardForm]]]]
```

Examples:

```
 explist = {(f[x] + h[y])/g[y], (f[x] + h[y])/2, (3 + Sin[t])/(5), 
 (1/y) Sin[x], f[22/7, (1/4) Sin[x]]/5}

 Grid[Prepend[ Transpose@{#, frctnBx /@ #} &@explist, {"expr", "frctnBx@expr"}],
  Dividers -> All, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 24}]
```

[image]