# Is there a way to identify a symbolic fraction?

Tags: pattern-matching, symbolic

Is there a way to use `Head` to detect a symbolic fraction? In particular I find,

```
Head[a/b]
Head[1/5]
```

> Times
>
> Rational

where I would like to get `Head[a/b] = Rational`. I want to test if a symbolic expression is a fraction so I can use it in another function.

Comment: Rational is for numbers. Since `a` and `b` can be anything, since they are just symbols, I do not think it makes sense to say `a/b` is rational. If all you want is to check for the form, may be you can look at `FullForm[a/b]` and check for this form in your function by pattern matching?

Comment: Related: [(18987)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18987/121)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems to me that `Denominator` helps a lot:

```
fractionQ = Denominator@# =!= 1 &;

fractionQ /@ {a/b, 1/a, 1/5, b/2, a, .5}
(* {True, True, True, True, False, False} *)
```

Answer (score 8):

The goal is not so clear for me, but probably something like this can be useful:

```
test = MatchQ[#, HoldPattern[_. _^-1] | _Rational | HoldPattern[_ Rational[1, _]] ] &

test /@ {a/b, 1/a, 1/5, a, .5, b/2}
```

> ```
> {True, True, True, False, False, True}
> ```

Notice the dot in `_.`, it is crucial for detecting `1/a` since there is no `Times` really.