# Simplify Sin[x]/x to Sinc[x]

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

I have an expression in the form of $\tt \frac{Sin[x]}{x}$ that I would like to simplify to the form of `Sinc[x]`. I've tried the `Simplify`, `FullSimplify` and `TrigReduce`, but none of them work.

```
Simplify[Sin[x]/x]
FullSimplify[Sin[x]/x]
TrigReduce[Sin[x]/x]
```

all gives the result $\tt\frac{Sin[x]}{x}$. However

```
FullSimplify[Sin[x]/x == Sinc[x]]
```

gives `True`.

I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to tell MMA that I prefer `Sinc[x]` than `Sin[x]/x`, so that it can simplify $\sin(x)/x$ to $\mathrm{sinc}(x)$?
2. How doees `TransformationFunctions` and `ComplexityFunction` work in `Simplify`? Could you give some examples and explanations of how to use them to control the form of the outcome expression? Can I use them to let *Mathematica* apply my own defined simplify rules (for example in this case `Sin[x]/x -> Sinc[x]`)? I found their documents are difficult to understand for me.
   Thanks.

---

***update***
    `FullSimplify[Sin[x]/x,ComplexityFunction->Composition[StringLength,ToString,InputForm]]` also doesn't work. However,

```
Composition[StringLength,ToString,InputForm][Sin[x]/x]
```

gives 8 which is larger than

```
Composition[StringLength,ToString,InputForm][Sinc[x]]
```

which gives 7.

Comment: There are plenty of examples on this site for [`TransformationFunctions`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=TransformationFunctions) and [`ComplexityFunction`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=ComplexityFunction)... Also search for `LeafCount` both in the docs and this site and also see [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4281/5)

Comment: Re: _I found their documents are difficult to understand for me_ . Yep, the docs need some time to get used to them, but be sure to invest enough time to get through that hurdle

Comment: take a look at the questions automatically appearing on the right of the page. they may help

Comment: Related: [(7741)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7741/121) and [(18144)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18144/121)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A transformation function is just any function that will take an expression to another expression you consider equivalent. For example, we can make one that takes `Sin` to `Sinc`.

```
sinctrans[expr_] := expr /. Sin[x_] :> x Sinc[x]
```

You could just use that by itself to do this substitution, but you can also add it to the `TransformationFunctions` of `Simplify` to do something more complicated.

```
Simplify[Sum[((-1)^n*x^(2*n))/(2*n + 1)!, 
     {n, 0, Infinity}], TransformationFunctions -> 
     {Automatic, sinctrans}]
(* Sinc[x] *)
```

Mathematica will generally use `Sinc[x]` over `Sin[x]/x` in these circumstances, since it has fewer elements. We can contrive an example where that's not the case and then introduce a `ComplexityFunction` that harshly penalizes any expression containing `Sin`:

```
Simplify[Sin[x], TransformationFunctions -> 
     {Automatic, sinctrans}, ComplexityFunction -> 
     (LeafCount[#1] + If[FreeQ[#1, Sin], 0, 10^3] & )]
(* x Sinc[x] *)
```

Comment: Alternatively, `ComplexityFunction -> (Count[#, Sin[_], {-2}] &)`