# How to use TransformationFunctions on a compound expression?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I was trying to answer this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30312/replacing-gamma-at-half-integers-by-double-factorial) but having hard time with the correct way to write the transformation rule.

Trying to write a rule to transform `Gamma[1/2 + n]` to `Sqrt[Pi] (Factorial2[2 *(n - 1/2) - 1])/2^(n - 1/2)`. Will worry about the conditions when this transformation is valid later on. I now can't even make `Simplify` use this rule.

The rule is being invoked (I add a `Print` and see it there), but the final result returned by the transformation function is not being used or returned)

I looked at this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18144/using-hold-correctly-with-simplify-and-complexityfunction) and tried what is there, but still no success. These are my attempts. The result of the `Simplify` command should return `Sqrt[Pi] (Factorial2[2 *(n - 1/2) - 1])/2^(n - 1/2)` in this example.

I am not sure if it is scoping issue. Can one use an `If` or `Cases` in the transformationFunction or must it be based only on the syntax of `/. :>`?

I wish help has more examples. Only 3 basic examples are shown and that is it.

When an expression being used inside the tranformation function (like in this case, `Gamma[1/2 + n]` then `n` here is taken as global symbol, right? I mean it will not have a $$n or it? That what seems to be the case. So I do not see why any of these are not working.

```
ClearAll[n, f, e];
f = # /. Gamma[1/2 + n] :> Sqrt[Pi] (Factorial2[2*(n - 1/2) - 1])/2^(n - 1/2) &
Simplify[Gamma[1/2 + n], TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, f}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ClearAll[n, f, e];
f[e_] := If[MatchQ[e, Gamma[1/2 + n]], Sqrt[Pi] (Factorial2[2 *(n - 1/2) - 1])/2^(n - 1/2), e]
Simplify[Gamma[1/2 + n], TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, f}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TransformationFunctions.html

Comment: Perhaps I didn't read it attentively enough, sorry if I'm rushing. But if the `ComplexityFunction` doesn't value the new transformed expression as less complex than the original, it won't transform anything. Could this be it?

Comment: @Rojo thanks. good point. I have not thought of this. So what is one supposed to do in this case? Use the `ComplexityFunction` in addition somehow? Will look into it.

Comment: `Simplify` and friends' objective is to "more or less" minimize the `ComplexityFunction`, and you can help out by allowing additional transformations to be tried on parts or subparts. If you don't specify a ComplexityFunction for which the expression you aim to get is simpler, then you are not really trying to simplify.

Comment: Try adding a ComplexityFunction that punishes `Gamma`, such as `ComplexityFunction -> 
 Function[exp, 
  Count[exp, Gamma, Infinity, Heads -> True] 1000 + LeafCount@exp]`

Comment: Arrgh, I had just been working on answering the question you referred to when I saw you asked an additional question on this. I'm afraid there's quite a bit of overlap. Anyway, there are several problems with your solution: 1) it only works with the literal symbol `n` and 2) it doesn't take the constraints on `n` (positive integer) into account. See my answer for that.

Comment: I did say `Will worry about the conditions when this transformation is valid later on` my question here was on why the transformation was not being taken into account. a separate issue.

Comment: Nasser, please consider posting and Accepting your own solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Rojo hint. The problem was that the complexity function needs to be also taken care of. Hence the final result works as below

```
ClearAll[n, tf, e, cf];
cf[e_] := Count[e, Gamma, Infinity, Heads -> True] 1000 + LeafCount@e 
tf[e_] := If[MatchQ[e, Gamma[1/2 + n]], Sqrt[Pi] (Factorial2[2 *(n - 1/2) - 1])/2^(n - 1/2), e]

Simplify[Gamma[1/2 + n], TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, tf}, ComplexityFunction -> cf]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Simplify[Gamma[1/3 + n], TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, tf}, ComplexityFunction -> cf]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]