# Simplify square roots

Tags: simplifying-expressions

If I simplify an equation like Sqrt[A^5]+5*Sqrt[A^3]-Sqrt[A] then I get (A^2+5A-1)*Sqrt[A] with no problems.
But when I need to simplify Sqrt[(A^5) (1 + a) ] + 5 Sqrt[A^3 (1 + a)] - Sqrt[A (1 + a)] as (A^2+5A-1)Sqrt[A (1 + a)], I get the original one:

> ```
> Sqrt[(A^5) (1 + a) ] + 5 Sqrt[A^3 (1 + a)] - Sqrt[A (1 + a)]
> ```
>
> I tried `Simplify`, `FullSimplify`, `Expand`, `Factor`, but they all return the original equation.
>   What is going on behind the scenes ?

Answer (score 12):

I believe there are three issues here.

1. Your expressions are not generally equivalent.  You must specify assumptions that make them so.
2. The form `A*Sqrt[A]` is automatically transformed into `A^(3/2)`.  To get your desired output you will need to [`Hold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Hold.html) the expression.
3. If attempting to use (Full)`Simplify` you will need to specify a [`ComplexityFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ComplexityFunction.html) that sees your desired form as simpler, e.g. [How can I simplify $\log(512)$ to $9\log(2)$?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39351/121).  (See also [Using Hold correctly with Simplify and ComplexityFunction](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18144/121) if you choose this more difficult route.)

The assumption can be given to `Simplify`:

```
Simplify[Sqrt[(A^3)], A > 0]
```

> A^(3/2)

Or you can in this case use [`PowerExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PowerExpand.html):

> PowerExpand converts (a b)^c to a^cb^c, whatever the form of c is.
>
> The transformations made by PowerExpand are correct in general only if c is an integer or a and b are positive real numbers.

```
Sqrt[(A^3)] // PowerExpand
```

> ```
> A^(3/2)
> ```

Since the form `A*Sqrt[A]` requires holding, perhaps it is best as a formatting operation:

```
Unprotect[Power];
Format[x_^(3/2)] := Defer[x*Sqrt[x]]
Protect[Power];
```

Now:

```
A^(3/2)
```

> ```
> A Sqrt[A]
> ```

---

Addressing your updated question you can use methods above exactly as illustrated:

```
expr = Sqrt[A^5] + 5*Sqrt[A^3] - Sqrt[A];

Simplify[expr, A > 0]
```

> ```
> Sqrt[A] (-1 + 5 A + A^2)
> ```

```
expr // PowerExpand // Simplify
```

> ```
> Sqrt[A] (-1 + 5 A + A^2)
> ```

Comment: Same with 9.01 (automatic simplification)

Comment: I want to take a common factor Sqrt[A] from an expression like: Sqrt[A^5]+5*Sqrt[A^3]-Sqrt[A], and the result should be simplified as : (A^2+5A-1)*Sqrt[A].

Comment: @Bilal The methods I showed will work.  See my update.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, yes you are right,they work in this example, but in my case it is not working , I want to simplify Sqrt[(A^5) (1 + a) ] + 5 Sqrt[A^3 (1 + a)] - Sqrt[A (1 + a)] as (A^2+5A-1)Sqrt[A (1 + a)]

Comment: @Bilal Please include that example and the output you desire in your question.