# How to simplify 1 - Cos[2x] to 2 Sin[x]^2?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

I want to reduce all `Cos[2 x]` to `1 - 2Sin[x]^2`, it seems *Mathematica* will always simplify `2 Sin[x]^2` to `1  Cos[2x]`, but how to do the reverse?

Comment: How about `TrigExpand@Cos[2 x] /. Cos[a_]^2 :> (1 - Sin[a]^2)` ?

Comment: you forgot the Square, `Cos[2x]=1-2 Sin[x]^2`

Comment: These seem related: [(4281)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4281/121),
[(7741)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7741/121),
[(7799)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7799/121),
[(18144)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18144/121),
[(19855)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19855/121)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way will be to add it to the definition of `Cos` by `Unprotect`ing it.

```
Unprotect[Cos]
Cos[2 x] := 1 - 2 Sin[x]^2
Protect[Cos]
```

Then evaluating the following:

```
2 Cos[2 x] + 3 x Cos[2 x] + Tan[x] Sin[x] Cos[2 x] + Exp[Tan[Cos[2 x]]]
```

gives:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Which you can further `Simplify` if you so please. Notice that the desired replacement has occurred everywhere there's `Cos[2x]`

Comment: @SimonRochester: Why do you think it does not work?

Comment: @Wizard That was a comment about the previous version. This version should work fine...although maybe a little heavy handed...

Answer (score 4):

Expanding `Cos[2 x]` to `1 - Sin[x]^2` and simplifying are somewhat opposite procedures.  [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html) basically reduces the leaf count (see [How do I invoke the default complexity function?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26172/how-do-i-invoke-the-default-complexity-function) for more details).  As we can see the number of leaves in the goal is twice the numbers of leaves in the starting expression:

```
LeafCount /@ {Cos[2 x], 1 - Sin[x]^2}
(*  {4, 8}  *)

TreeForm /@ {Cos[2 x], 1 - Sin[x]^2} // GraphicsRow
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The basic built-in function for performing the sort transformation the OP desires is [`TrigExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrigExpand.html).  But `TrigExpand` applies a different identity to `Cos[2 x]` than the desired one:

```
TrigExpand[Cos[2 x]]
(*  Cos[x]^2 - Sin[x]^2  *)
```

This may be acceptable, since it is one of the three common forms of the double-angle identity.  Generally, I try to figure out how *Mathematica* works and adapt my thinking to conform -- that is, I try to learn how to use the tool in the way it was designed to be used and to work *with* the tool and not *against* it.  But *Mathematica* is a quite flexible tool, so if the identity in terms of `Sin[x]` only is desired, it is possible to use it.

One could replace `Cos[x]^2` by `1 - Sin[x]^2` in the output of `TrigExpand` as suggested in a comment by [Stefan R](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5678/stefan-r).  One could also replace `Cos[2 x]` by `1 - Sin[x]^2` directly.  This seems the simplest way.

```
Cos[2 x] /. {Cos[2 t_] :> 1 - 2 Sin[t]^2}
(*  1 - 2 Sin[x]^2  *)
```

---

In a complicated expression like [RunnyKine's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5709/runnykine), the possible goals ramify.  `TrigExpand` does a really bad job ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeOu2.png)) as evaluated by a human-readable aesthetic.  If we make the expression slightly more complicated with a `Cos[4 x]`,

```
expr = 2 Cos[4 x] + 3 x Cos[2 x] + Tan[x] Sin[x] Cos[2 x] + Exp[Tan[Cos[2 x]]];
```

then is the goal to expand only `Cos[2 x]`, like this?

```
expr /. {Cos[2 t_] :> 1 - 2 Sin[t]^2}
(*
  E^Tan[1 - 2 Sin[x]^2] + 2 Cos[4 x] +            <-- N.B. Cos[4 x]
   3 x (1 - 2 Sin[x]^2) + Sin[x] (1 - 2 Sin[x]^2) Tan[x]
*)
```

Or should we expand all cosines with an even coefficient, like this?

```
expr //.                                      (*  <-- N.B. ReplaceRepeated  *)
 {Cos[a_Integer?EvenQ t_] :> 1 - 2 Sin[a t/2]^2}
(*
  E^Tan[1 - 2 Sin[x]^2] + 3 x (1 - 2 Sin[x]^2) +
   2 (1 - 2 Sin[2 x]^2) +                         <-- N.B. Sin[2 x]
   Sin[x] (1 - 2 Sin[x]^2) Tan[x]
*)
```

Or maybe the goal is to convert all sines and cosines to terms of `Sin[x]`, unless there are leftover terms of `Cos[x]`, which can be done like this:

```
expr //.
 {Cos[a_Integer?EvenQ t_] :> 1 - 2 Sin[a t/2]^2, 
  Sin[a_Integer?EvenQ t_] :> 2 Sin[a t/2] Cos[a t/2],
  Cos[t_]^(p_Integer?EvenQ) :> (1 - Sin[t]^2)^(p/2)}
(*
  E^Tan[1 - 2 Sin[x]^2] + 3 x (1 - 2 Sin[x]^2) + 
   2 (1 - 8 Sin[x]^2 (1 - Sin[x]^2)) + Sin[x] (1 - 2 Sin[x]^2) Tan[x]
*)
```

And what, if anything, to do about `Tan[x]`?

Comment: Thanks, in fact my expression is quite simple: `ds2=dr^2 + 1/2 (d\[Theta]^2 + 2 d\[Phi]^2) r^2 - 
 1/2 d\[Theta]^2 r^2 1 - 2 Sin[\[Phi]]^2`, and I get what I want by your method, `ds2/. {Cos[2 t_] :>  1 - 2 Sin[t]^2} // Simplify`

Comment: @vanabel  You're welcome.  Sometimes `Simplify` will convert the expression back to terms of `Cos[2 x]` and sometimes it will combine the `Sin[x]` with other terms and not convert it.  Trig. is tricky to deal with.  BTW, I would not redefine a basic function like `Cos` in the way RunnyKine does.  Since there are, I believe, many rules built into *Mathematica* about sine and cosine, I would be afraid the redefinition would break something.  Just what that is would be difficult to predict.

Answer (score 2):

You could go ahead and modify the mathematica output manually by defining exactly what you want to have transformed. In your case this would look like this:

```
MakeBoxes[Cos[2*x_], StandardForm] := RowBox[{MakeBoxes[1 - 2 Sin[x]^2]}];
```

This effectively turns every occurrence of `Cos[2x]` in `StandardForm` into `1 - 2 Sin[x]^2`. I use this to get a certain standard notation for dirac delta functions.