# Simplify a expression with cos 2x

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

I would like to simplify the following expression :

```
r Cos[γ[t]] + Sqrt[l^2 - r^2/2 + 1/2 r^2 Cos[2 γ[t]]]
```

by using the mathematical expression :

```
Cos[2 x]=1 - 2 Sin[x]^2
```

A similar topic was already created:

[How to simplify 1 - Cos[2x] to 2 Sin[x]^2?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/89026/how-to-simplify-1-cos2x-to-2-sinx2)

However, I would like to use a very simple method for a *Mathematica* beginner.

May you advice a **simple solution** to obtain this kind of reduction ?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure why you would think this is a difficult problem. A simple replacement works:

```
r Cos[γ[t]] + Sqrt[l^2 - r^2/2 + 1/2 r^2 Cos[2 γ[t]]] /. 
  Cos[2  a_] :> 1 - 2 Sin[a]^2 // FullSimplify
(* r Cos[γ[t]] + Sqrt[l^2 - r^2 Sin[γ[t]]^2] *)
```